# jasper report No part components bundle registered for namespace

Tags: jasper-reports

I'm using jasper report book, in jaspersoft studio it's working fine but when i deploy it in web environement i have this error : `net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No part components bundle registered for namespace  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts.`

Here is the full stacktrace :

```
    RusReportStarter.startProcess_aroundBody0: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No part components bundle registered for namespace  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts. [361]
net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: No part components bundle registered for namespace  http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports/parts.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.part.PartComponentsEnvironment.getBundle(PartComponentsEnvironment.java:141)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.part.PartComponentsEnvironment.getManager(PartComponentsEnvironment.java:161)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.part.FillPart.<init>(FillPart.java:59)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.part.FillParts.<init>(FillParts.java:54)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.<init>(PartReportFiller.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.PartReportFiller.<init>(PartReportFiller.java:91)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.createReportFiller(JRFiller.java:219)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFiller.fill(JRFiller.java:84)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fill(JasperFillManager.java:456)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperFillManager.fillReport(JasperFillManager.java:863)
```

any solutions ?

Answer (score 0):

I find the solution, i had to go to jasper_extensions.properties in my project and add this line `net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.parts=net.sf.jasperreports.parts.PartComponentsExtensionsRegistryFactory`.
It solved the problem.